# Increasing font size for links on hover changes background color size, how to stop this?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, resize, hover

I'm new to html & css so bear with me. I feel it's something simple that I'm missing but I can't out what.

For example, I have a navigation bar like this:

```
<nav id="navbar">
    <a class="nav" href="#home">Home</a> &#124;
    <a class="nav" href="#link1">Link 1</a> &#124;
</nav>
```

With css:

```
#navbar {
    font-family: "Tahoma", Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18pt;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    color: white;
    margin:15px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

I've set the links font to increase in size and change color when I hover over them:

```
a.nav:hover {
    color: red;
    font-size: larger;
}
```

Which works fine, but when i hover over the links the background of my nav bar increases downwards a bit as if to fit my new text size. How can I stop the background from changing size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `line-height:18pt` for your hover, it will stop the anchor increasing it's original height:

```
a.nav:hover {
  color: red;
  font-size: larger;
  line-height:18pt;
}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4dmhqka/1/)

Comment: You're welcome but I just checked in ie and it seems to have problems as it's such a rubbish browser!   I'm just looking at a fix

Comment: Thanks so much, really appreciate it!